# Index Match Lookup - LAST value

Tags: excel, indexing, match

Trying to find the LAST value returned from an IndexMatch search, currently it's showing the FIRST.

Tried every variable and configuration of MAX I could think of and multiple Google searches.

```
=INDEX([DG.xlsx]rawdata!$D$3:$D$30000,MATCH(A4,[DG.xlsx]rawdata!$B$3:$B$30000,0))
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use MATCH as it will only return the first match.

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX([DG.xlsx]rawdata!$D:$D,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW([DG.xlsx]rawdata!$B$3:$B$30000)/(A4=[DG.xlsx]rawdata!$B$3:$B$30000),1))
```